# Issues with building scala in Intellij (14.1)

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have created a project in IntelliJ, which consists of a couple of scala modules (maven build). Intellij version 14.1.4, Scala plugin 1.5.2

The compilation and build worked fine until today. Now I get an error, which looks like Intellij does not find the compiler anymore

```
Error:scalac: 
 while compiling: /home..//test.scala
    during phase: global=terminal, atPhase=xsbt-analyzer
 library version: version 2.10.4
compiler version: version 2.10.4
```

....

```
uncaught exception during compilation: java.io.IOException
Error:scalac: No such file or directory
```

When I execute the maven build directly, all is fine. I've also tried to include scalac in $Path. Additionally I've
changed and downloaded the SDKs in the project settings but with no effect.

Is this a bug ?

I've seen a similar issue mentioned here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Building-with-IntelliJ
but the described workaround does not help.

Comment: Is scalc available as command in your terminal?

Comment: scalac is available, yes

Comment: Possibly this: [SCL-8776 "The system cannot find the path specified" error when building Scala project in IntelliJ after moving project files.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8776)

Comment: Could scala have moved, due to a version upgrade, for example?

Comment: @Mark: Thx...might be the issue...will check next week

Comment: When I am deleting the project locally and re-fetching the project from Git, it works again....so I guess it is a bug